# Can "to-infinitive phrase" be an apposition of "that"?

Tags: appositives

For example,

> That, to quit smoking and take care of yourself, is up to you.

1. is this sentence grammatically correct? (I think it's grammatically correct if we think of "to quit smoking and take care of yourself" as a phrase referring to "that")
2. Is "to quit smoking and take care of yourself" the apposition of "that"? I mean it's referring to "that" ?
3. Is it okay to get rid of commas ? (I think it's okay, but there seems to be a little difference in meaning)

Comment: No, it's ungrammatical, and there's no apposition. In any case, why would you want to construct such a sentence?

Comment: @BillJ Just for a check on whether it can be grammatically possible. Isn't there any grammatically natural sentence, regarding my question?

Comment: It would only make sense if it were preceded by other sentences. But, if it were, *that* would be understood to refer back to them—and there would be no real reason to add the explanatory information in the first place. (*Many people quit smoking and take care of themselves. But should you? That is up to you.*) While the standalone sentence is *grammatical* (syntactic) at the level of a mental exercise (remove the parenthetical information in order to evaluate it), it's strange.

Comment: Also, *that* does refer to *to quit smoking and take care of yourself*, but the longer phrase is neither a pronoun nor a noun phrase—so this isn't an example of an appositive (which has that requirement). If you removed the commas, you'd ***probably*** also have to remove *that* from the start of the sentence. Unless, again, it came *after* something else that make it understandable in context. *He said that. That to quit smoking and take care of yourself is up to you.* But, also again, it would be odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.

"That" can refer to anything.  For example:

> I like that, this idea of picking one's battles.
>
> I like that, to pick one's battles.
>
> That, to pick one's battles, is the key to good parenting, in my opinion.